# Remove gravity form action from woocommerce page

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, gravity-forms-plugin

So i have a hidden gravity form ( triggers gravity flow) on my WooCommerce page. This triggers when a product is added to cart but this is not what i want.

I can remove this behavior by removing the action on init. The actions below are the behaviors I don't want.

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_gravityflow_after_submit' );
  function remove_gravityflow_after_submit(){
      remove_action( 'gform_entry_pre_handle_confirmation', array( gravity_flow(), 'after_submission' ), 9 );
      remove_action( 'gform_pre_handle_confirmation', array( gravity_flow(), 'after_submission' ), 9 );
      remove_action( 'gform_after_submission', array( gravity_flow(), 'after_submission' ), 9 );
      remove_action( 'gform_post_add_entry', array( gravity_flow(), 'action_gform_post_add_entry' ), 10 );
  }
```

this works fine so I can manually submit the form somewhere else later.

The problem with this approach is that it disables all my other graavity forms. So that got me thinking.. the solution will be to only remove this behavior if I'm on a WooCommerce page. Which would work if I can get it to work of which I haven't just yet

my solution is

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_gravityflow_after_submit' );
    function remove_gravityflow_after_submit(){
    if ( is_woocommerce() || is_product() ){
        remove_action( 'gform_entry_pre_handle_confirmation', array( gravity_flow(), 'after_submission' ), 9 );
        remove_action( 'gform_pre_handle_confirmation', array( gravity_flow(), 'after_submission' ), 9 );
        remove_action( 'gform_after_submission', array( gravity_flow(), 'after_submission' ), 9 );
        remove_action( 'gform_post_add_entry', array( gravity_flow(), 'action_gform_post_add_entry' ), 10 );
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work mainly because I think WooCommerce is not loaded at this point so the conditionals don't work. Another alternative will be to add the removed actions back

```
if ( is_woocommerce() ) { ... remove action } else { add_action }
```

but since I can't use conditionals in 'init' i can't also make this approach work either. What will be the best way of doing something like this? I also tried the 'template_redirect' hook to remove but it doesn't work either.

Comment: https://kinsta.com/blog/disable-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: i still need the plugin to work... not just perform a particular action on said page. Thanks for the suggestion though @MujeebuRahman